# JSP debug line not highlighted

Tags: eclipse, jsp, debugging

Something has happened to my debug environment.  I'm using Eclipse Mars, Tomcat and JSP.  The current debug line is not highlighted when I hit a break point in a JSP file and try to step (F6).  I can still step through the code and the debug window show's the line # in the JSP file I'm on but its not highlighted in the code window.  The break point is properly highlighted when its hit but a Source Not Found error is displayed when I try to step.  I've added projects to the Tomcat source and classpath tabs via debug configurations and tried a clean project without luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the Eclipse work space had problems.  I created a new one, added projects. libs and servers and made my personal settings.  All is well again.